# Size of the Scrollbar in ion-list

Tags: html, ios, ionic-framework

I have an ion-list in html that is used in an iOS-App and the ion-item has a padding in all directions. I have the problem, that the scrollbar in the items (that one that can be used to show the button on the right) only covers the text in the items of the list, but not the margins.
The result is, that you can see the button at the top and at the bottom of the scrollbar, when it is moved.

How can I adjust the width of the scrollbar so that it covers the margins, too?